# Yet Another Case of findViewById() Returning null in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Yes, I know there are several topics on the matter of *findViewById() returns null* and no, none of them seems to solve my problem.

Most of the solutions are about the timing on which the `findViewId()` is called, which I believe is not my case.

So, I have a `MyFragment` class, for fragments that are displayed on a `ViewPager`. The class follows the suggested pattern for its creation (using a `newInstance()` method).

In my `onCreateView` method, I find some `Views` in my newly inflated view (`rootView`), set some properties (typeface, text...) and listeners. One of the `Views` (in this example, `problematicLayout`) is supposed to be visibile/hidden depending on a condition.

**Everything works fine until I rotate the device.** As I do it, all the views in the `onCreateView()` are correctly found and their properties are set. `problematicLayout = (LinearLayout ) rootView.findViewById(R.id.problematicLayout)`, however, is returning `null`. If I pause and browse through the View hierarchy
 **(rootView --> mChildren --> and so on)** I can see that `problematicLayout` has its `ID = -1!`

I've also tried moving my `findViewById(R.id.problematicLayout)` to the `onViewCreated()`, using the method signature's view, only to achieve the same result.

If I comment the line and never make the `problematicLayout` invisible/gone, I don't have the same issue.

Why is this happening? Why is this `problematicLayout's` ID being set to -1, causing `findViewById()` to return null? What am I missing here?

```
public static Fragment newInstance(Context context,
    int position, Answer answer) {

    MyFragment frag = new MyFragment ();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable(STUFF NAME, STUFF);
    frag.setArguments(args);

    return frag;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

    ScorllView someScrollView = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.someScrollView);
    // ... other views, setting their event listners, etc.

    LinearLayout problematicLayout = (LinearLayout ) rootView.findViewById(R.id.problematicLayout);

    setProblematicLayout(problematicLayout);

    // ... setting other listeners, etc.
    return rootView;

}

public void setProblematicLayout(LinearLayout layout)
{
     if(!condition)
     {
         layout.setVisibiliy(View.GONE)
         // ... set listeners and properties for views inside the layout.
     }
     else
     {
         layout.setVisibiliy(View.INVISIBLE);
     }

}
```

Comment: are you sure the said layout is inside `my_fragment.xml` ?

Comment: Do you have landscape/portrait variants of the layout, and the view only in the other?

Comment: Please add your layout file

Comment: Yep. Otherwise, I would get the Exception right away, and not just after rotating the device.

Comment: D'oh @laalto. You're right. I had forgotten to set the id for the 'problematiclayout' in my landscape variant of the layout! You can type an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're using layout resource variants for portrait/landscape, make sure the view is found in both.

Comment: Yeah, I had forgotten about that for this particular layout. Dumb moment, thanks (will accept after the 8 min threshold).